# Symmetrically encrypt data off Salesforce and decrypt in Apex?

Tags: apex, encryption, crypto

We want to encrypt data generated in a Ruby on Rails app to be encrypted, passed to Salesforce, and then be decrypted in Apex code.

This seems like a clear case for using `Crypto.decrypt`:

> **[decrypt(algorithmName, privateKey, initializationVector, cipherText)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm#apex_System_Crypto_decrypt)**
>
> Decrypts the Blob cipherText using the specified algorithm, private
>   key, and initialization vector. Use this method to decrypt blobs
>   encrypted using a third party application or the encrypt method.
>
> *[...]*
>
> ```
> Blob exampleIv = Blob.valueOf('Example of IV123');
> Blob key = Crypto.generateAesKey(128);
> Blob data = Blob.valueOf('Data to be encrypted');
> Blob encrypted = Crypto.encrypt('AES128', key, exampleIv, data);
>
> Blob decrypted = Crypto.decrypt('AES128', key, exampleIv, encrypted);
> String decryptedString = decrypted.toString();
> System.assertEquals('Data to be encrypted', decryptedString);
> ```

But I can't find anywhere how to do this using something other than a `Blob` generated within Apex. As far as I can tell, I need to get this key out of Salesforce to use it elsewhere, but I can't figure out how.

I also found examples on this page,
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class , but it also doesn't tell me how to get my key between my external app and my Salesforce org. It just says to store it in a custom setting or custom object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much (any?) support for binary data but over HTTP is common to pass data encoded as a base 64 string and you can turn that into a Blob using:

```
String inputString = ...;
Blob b = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(String inputString)
```